# Angular 5 deployment with Apache2

Tags: jenkins, apache2, angular5

I am working with a project having its front-end in angular. I am having issue when deploying it to server. The project was deployed using jenkins and the project folder angProject1 was deployed in /var/www/html/dms folder. 
The /etc/apache2/sites-available/dmsproxy.conf file have

```
ServerName dms.xxxxxx.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dms/angProject1
```

I have added the .htaccessfile to /var/www/html/dms/angProject1:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

And /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf contains :

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/dms">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I can access the dms.xxxxxx.com page, but when I try for dms.xxxxxx.com/opendms etc, it is not working (ERROR:The requested url was not found). Tried adding # as dms.xxxxxx.com/#/opendms too, but it redirects to dms.xxxxxx.com file.

The base href in index.html is `<base href="./">`.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Changed the

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/dms">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

inside the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and now the application is reading the .htaccess file. Also my .htaccess is changed to:

```
RewriteEngine On  
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Changed the base href to `<base href = "angProject1"/>`